# Fastest way to conditionally update column in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, performance, sql-update

I have two tables

`create table A(id text, data text, has_b boolean default false);`

`create table B(id text, a_id text, data text);`

No Primary keys, no indexes. Field `a_id` from `table B` will match `id` from `table A`.

I want to set field `has_b` to true if `A.id` is referenced in `B.a_id`.
This is one time update after creating the database and inserting all the data, so I can do any manipulation to the database if needed.

Currently I am using following update statement, but it is too slow (I have over 500 mln of records to update).

```
UPDATE A SET has_b = TRUE
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM B WHERE a_id = A.id limit 1);
```

I have also tried this one, but with similar effect:

```
UPDATE A SET has_B = TRUE FROM B WHERE a_id = A.id;
```

Is there a faster way to make such update in the database? Or maybe some other solution?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: Check the [execution plans](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/using-explain.html)

Comment: `UPDATE A SET has_b = TRUE 
WHERE has_b <> True AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM B WHERE B.a_id = A.id);` .... **No Primary keys, no indexes....** Field `a_id from table B` will match `id from table A`  ... PKs and FK's (-->>indexes) would certainly help

Comment: Unfortunately before executing the update has_b is set to false for all rows, so above would not make it faster. But thank you for the suggestion.
I have tried putting the indexes but after that the update is actually slower.

Comment: I don't think this can be improved.